# How to disable re-calling API after onClick and execute refetch the react-query hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

for example, i've a component to fetch and call an API, but that query by default is `enabled: false` and i should fire that by onClick:

```
const query = useQuery('key', fetch, { enabled: false })

const exec = () => query.refetch()

return <button onClick={exec}>Load</button>
```

But i've a new API call after every clicks on the button, actually i want to cancel re-calling the API still the cached data is available and is not stale...

I there any way to implement something like refetch to retrieve cached data but without re-calling the API? our basically react-query has a re-call for any data reteive?

in fact, our data doesn't change frequently and is fix for 2-3 days...

other words, our clients frequently work with nested drop-downs with same API calls and i want to reduce same key queries... imagine that, something like category to select a brand for products

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set `staleTime` and `cacheTime` options of your query to `Infinity` to keep your cache always available

[image: react-query docs screenshot]

https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery

Comment: I've tried with these configs, but doesn't work and I think `query.refetch()` calls API again and there is no way to stop that

Answer (score 0):

> imagine that, something like category to select a brand for products

This is a classic example for react-query where you want to put all dependencies of your query into your cache key (see [the official docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key)). That way, the caches won't override each other, and you'll instantly get the values back from the cache if they are available. Not that you will *also* get a background refetch, and that's where `staleTime` comes in. If you don't want that, set a higher staleTime to only retrieve the value from the cache if it exists.

To illustrate, let's take your example of a select of categories for products:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(null)
  
  const { data } = useQuery(['key', category], () => fetchProducts(category), { enabled: !!brand, staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 3 })

  <CategorySelect onSelect={setCategory} />
}
```

Multiple things going on here:

1. I have some local state, where I store the selected category
2. This selection drives the query. The query is disabled as long as I have no selection, but enables once the user makes a selection
3. every time the category changes, the query key changes, which will make react-query trigger a refetch automatically, for the new data
4. I've set the staleTime to 3 minutes. If I chose a category that I have already chosen, I will get data from the cache. Within 3 minutes, I will only get it from the cache. If my data is older, I will get it from the cache *and* the data will also be updated in the background.

Comment: Thanks, but can i use this method? `appQueryClient.getQueryData(key)` I mean a condition before calling the fetcher function, if has cached return the cached data otherwise, call the fetcher to fetch API... what is your opinion?

Comment: if you only want to fetch once, just set `staleTime: Infinity`. Note that gargabe collection still kicks in depending on `cacheTime` as soon as no one uses the query.